# Кишмя кишеть - что, чего или чем?

Tags: управление

"Там кишмя кишат микробы", "Там кишмя кишит микробов" или "Там кишмя кишит микробами"?

В нацкорпусе есть примеры на все случаи. Но меня смущает как минимум один из трёх.
Даже не знаю, где такие вещи надо проверять на нормативность.

~~~~

[[@olsa](/users/246/olsa)](/users/246/olsa), Инна!
С родительным - понятно. Мне он тоже не понравился сразу.
Вот с именительным... Чтобы не растекаться мыслею по древу. В словарях (на Грамоте - в т.ч.) речь идёт о глаголе. Насколько справедливо перенесение свойств глагола на весь фразеологизм? Группа-то она группа, но у глагола-то два значения, откуда уверенность, что оба они преносится на фразеологизм? Ко всему прочему, значение у фразеологизма - переносное. Движение тех же микробов заметить невозможно. Т.е. "кишмя кишеть" воспринимается как что-то наподобие "полным-полно".
Когда я вижу "Озеро кишмя кишит рыбой" я понимаю, кто и чем кишит. Когда читаю "Озеро кишмя кишит" предполагаю, что рыбой. Но "рыба кишмя кишит" вызывает вопрос - чем. 
(если непонятно, я могу более подробно объясниться, только позже)

[[@виктор1799](/users/895/%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%801799)](/users/895/%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%801799), Ожегов это хорошо. Но там *народ*. Он действительно может кишеть в прямом значении.

Comment: Не совсем поняла про переносное значение фразеологизма. Движение микробов без микроскопа заметить невозможно, но иногда можно заметить последствия этих движений (запах, цвет...) - смотря какой контекст. Главное что микробы могут беспорядочно двигаться, шевелиться или копошиться.   
Вроде бы словари (Ушакова, фразеологический Фёдорова) фиксируют совпадение значений глагола "кишеть" и фразеологизма "кишмя кишеть". У Ушакова только сказано, что фразеологизм - то же, что и глагол, только с оттенком усиления. Еще см. дополнение в моем ответе.

Comment: >Не совсем поняла про переносное значение фразеологизма
Глагол сам по себе не имет значения "быть в большом количестве", "переполнять что-то". Это (перенгосное) значение свойственно только фразеологизму. Поэтому перенесение *всех* свойств глагола (в т.ч. грамматических) на фразеологизм сомнительно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Меня в ряду приведенных вами примеров смущает "Там кишмя кишит микробов". У Розенталя был такой справочник "Управление в русском языке". Но там глагола *кишеть* нет. Фразеологизм *кишмя киш**е**ть* выступает как глагольная группа, следовательно сочетаемость с падежами определяется по глаголу *кишеть*. На Грамоте.ру в толковом словаре у этого глагола два значения : 1. Беспорядочно двигаться в различных направлениях (о множестве животных, людей). И тогда здесь без вариантов именительный падеж, никакого управления: *Рыба (кишмя) кишит в пруду. Народу тьма: так и кишат (<люди> кишмя кишат).* 2.Быть переполненным множеством живых существ. В таком значении глагол *кишеть* управляет творительным падежом: *Воздух (кишмя) кишел мошкарой. Привокзальная площадь (кишмя) кишела людьми.*

Посмотрела еще материалы по фразеологии, в частности ссылки на Мокиенко: КИШМЯ КИШИТ кем, чем. *О сплошной массе, множестве беспорядочно движущихся животных, насекомых, рыб или людей*.

Могу предположить, что вариант "Там кишмя кишит микробов" (т.е. управление родительным падежом) возник в связи с синонимией: кишмя кишит = 'полно, много, ... + *чего?*(род.пад.)' (словарь синонимов  на той же Грамоте.ру). Но в данном случае, на мой взгляд, все же надо учитывать, что выражение *кишмя кишит* используется в качестве глагольной группы, а не именной (с указанием на количество). Глагол КИШЕТЬ, как уже было сказано, может управлять только творительным падежом.

И спасибо за хороший вопрос.

Comment: С родительным понятно. 
В формой инфинитива - да, конечно, спасибо, это я опять а задумчивости был.

Answer (score 2):

Спасибо, Борис, за интересный вопрос. Люблю вопросы, для ответа на которые не нужно что-то перепечатывать, а просто надо опираться на свой речевой опыт. Правда, помня о том, что мой далекий собеседник не лыком шит, все же открыл хотя бы Ожегова. Там нашел пример: "Народ там так кишмя и кишит". Следуя логике этого словаря, надо признать верным первое из приведенных Вами вариантов. Но мне он не нравится. Помню с детства, что мы всегда говорили: "Там кишмя кишит лягушек(червяков, яблок в соседском саду, рыбы в реке...). Наверное,мы интуитивно использовали родительный падеж, потому что выражение "кишмя кишит" соотносилось нами с понятием "много". Поэтому мне больше нравится второй Ваш вариант: "Там кишмя кишит микробов".
P.S. Если Вам захочется мне ответить, пожалуйста, напечатав ответ, прочтите написанное и подправьте опечатки. Иногда трудно понять смысл некоторых Ваших слов. И еще (только не обижайтесь, ради Бога). Я учу студентов, чтобы они всегда перечитывали то, что предназначено для чужих глаз, и помнили, что написать с ошибками или описками текст не для себя, а для других людей - значит, проявить лень, которая скрывает неуважительное отношение к человеку, который пытается разобрать, что я впопыхах написал. Еще раз прошу, не обижайтесь и не ссылайтесь на какие-то мифические болячки.

Answer (score 2):

"Кишмя кишит" - фразеологизм, сращенная языковая фигура. Может употребляться в двух формах:

1. как глагол в значении "тусуется [в большом количестве]"; согласуется с существительным в именительном падеже. "На улице кишмя кишит народ". "В болоте кишмя кишат разные гады".
2. как наречие "много", "очень много", "полно", управляет и управляется существительным в родительном падеже. Тогда: "На улице народа кишмя кишит", "В болоте кишмя кишит лягушек и змей".

Comment: Да вроде разобрались уже.
Основной вопрос-то по форме, которая у вас под номером 1. 
народ и гады вполне себе могут кишеть. А вот микробы? Вы же не видите их движение? 

Но все равно - спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Из трех вариантов мне кажется сомнительным только второй: "Там кишмя кишит микробов". Выражение *кишмя кишат* можно приравнять к глаголу *кишат*, а вот к наречию *полно* или к числительному *много* - вряд ли (*Там кишмя кишит микробов*=*Там полно/много микробов*). Хотя фраза разговорная, а в разговорной речи может быть что угодно. Все-таки, думаю, это скорее глагольное выражение.

Нашла [здесь](http://dslov.narod.ru/fslov/f677.htm):

> Значение - то же, что кишеть (с
> оттенком усиления) (Толковый словарь
> Д. Н. Ушакова, 1935-1940)
>
> Кишеть - 1. Шевелиться, копошиться (о
> множестве мелких животных); перен.
> (чаще в сочетании со словами: так и).
> Находиться в большом количестве 2.
> кем-чем. Быть наполненным чем-нибудь,
> вмещать в себе множество каких-нибудь
> существ. (Толковый словарь Д. Н.
> Ушакова, 1935-1940)

P.S. Кстати, *полно* - точно наречие, а не неопределенно-количественное числительное??

**Дополнение-комментарий [[@behemothus](/users/445/behemothus)](/users/445/behemothus)**. Возможно, *кишмя кишеть чем* больше претендует на норму, чем *...кто*. В фразеологическом словаре Фёдорова (2008 г.) вариант с именительным падежом имеет статус разг. и экспрес., а второй с творительным не имеет никакой пометки:

**Кишмя кишеть** 
    Разг. Экспрес. **1.** О скоплении живых существ (обычно в водоёмах, лесных зарослях и т. п.). В кустах змеи да гады всякие кишмя кишат, а в парке звери дикие воют (Салтыков-Щедрин. Дикий помещик). Вода в болоте стояла чёрная, плавали радужные кружки, скакали наездники, крутились жучки — вертунки, кишмя кишела всякая нечисть (Пришвин. Крутоярский зверь). Было шумно и весело, хотя в тёплой, стоячей, непроницаемо-мутной воде кишмя кишели не только караси и головастики, но и пиявки, норовившие присосаться к голому заду и напиться крови (М. Алексеев. Драчуны). 
**2.** О местах, изобилующих какими-либо живыми существами. Леса по этой речке пока ещё не были вырублены, кишмя кишели зверем и птицей, а сама речка была забита рыбой (Ф. Абрамов. Собачья гордость).

Comment: спасибо, в тексте вопроса - продолжение.

Comment: >Возможно, кишмя кишеть чем больше претендует на норму, чем ...кто. В фразеологическом словаре Фёдорова (2008 г.) вариант с именительным падежом имеет статус разг. и экспрес., 

Если цитата точная, то нет. "Разг. Экспрес.", стоящее перед номером, должно относиться ко всем значениям, а не только к первому. Это общий принцип использования таких помет в словарях.

Answer (score 0):

Замечание в сторону.

Насколько я знаю, слово "кишеть" родственно глаголам "киснуть", "квасить" и первоначально обозначало бурление забродившей жидкости.  Однако это вряд ли поможет ответить на вопрос, потому что данный смысл у глагола давно стерся и не воспринимается носителями языка.

Comment: Отнюдь не стерся. Сам глагол это и значит, ну может, подвергся небольшим вариациям. мы говорили об этом. А вот "кишмя кишеть" - уже может значить 1) то же, что и сам глагол, 2) много, полно, даже "чересчур много".